# C# Type Casting, How Should be Implemented In Generics?

Tags: c#, generics, casting

I want to convert some text files into my code Entities.

these files contain entities information, for example, one contains Customer information, one contains Order information and another contains Supplier information.

I have already implemented string to entity type casting into the entity classes.

since reading text files and converting each lines into string is a common task for different entities, I used a generic class for reading text files and converting into entities.

```
public class TextToEntity<TEntity> 
{
    private string _txtfile { get; set; }
    public TextToEntity(string TextFile)
    {
        _txtfile = TextFile;
    }

    public List<TEntity> ReadText()
    {
        return File.ReadAllLines(_txtfile).Select(c =>
        {
            return (TEntity)c;
        }).ToList();
    }
}
```

the line

```
return (TEntity)c
```

cause the error

> cannot convert string to TEntity

I know I should give a constraint to the TextToEntity, something like:

```
public class TextToEntity<TEntity> where TEntity:Customer,Supplier,Order
```

but this is not the true syntax, what is the true form?

could anybody helps?

Comment: It doesn't matter what constraints you put on the class; the fact is that `File.ReadAllLines` returns an array of strings. So unless you have an implicit operator that converts from a string to your classes, it's just not going to work.

Comment: And that is NOT a cast problem - it is a parse problem. The classes returned are strings, you can not change string inheritance trees, so you must parse the strings, not cast them.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Customer, Supplier, Order already has the implicit type conversions from string, but TEntity should be constrained to them.

Comment: Seems like you need a common interface then. Maybe `IConvertableFromText`? I'd suggest `ISerializable`, but that's used :).

Comment: `TEntity` is always the same type. How this could return list of different types? `List<TEntity> ReadText()`

Comment: @HereticMonkey It looks good, but interfaces do not support operator

    public interface IStringConvertible<TEntity>
    {
        public static implicit operator TEntity(string s);
    }

is there any possible alternatives?

Comment: This looks like an X-Y problem. It is better if you explain what you want to do.

Comment: @apocalypse by return (TEntity)c

Comment: You mean text file contains always the same entity? For example: customers.txt contains only customer entity? No mixing allowed?

Answer (score 0):

I think your design is very bad... anyway here is a simple "hack":

```
public List<TEntity> ReadText()
{
    return File.ReadAllLines(_txtfile).Select(c =>
    {
        var method = typeof(TEntity).GetMethod("op_Explicit", new[] { typeof(string) });

        return (TEntity) method.Invoke(null, new[] { c });

    }).ToList ();
}
```